# difference between partialsubmit and singlesubmit in ICEfaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, form-submit, icefaces, renderpartial

I know the partial submit is used in icefaces 1.x, singlesubmit in icefaces 2.x and the  tag in icefaces 3.x. 
May someone tell me what is the substantial difference between them?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both partialSubmit and singleSubmit does the same thing. But in different ways.

Here is a typical form scenario:
user sees a form and starts interacting. Those forms have some fields. Some of those fields are required and are necessary to process the form. Other fields are optional.

When using partialSubmit, when a user leaves a field(onblur), iceface internally makes all other fields as non required so that the overall form can be submitted. Now since all other fields are optional and only the present field that you onblurred was required, icefaces can process the form. So it does all the validation checks and changes other elements that might have been affected and renders the whole page again with new changes. But here is the thing. The other fields that were deliberately made optional by icefaces, they also have their own validation mechnanisms. So when the form is processed, those field will show errors that they are not filled, or the password field cannot be null and all that. But since the user has not engaged other fields of the form, these errors should not be triggerred. This was the drawback of partialSubmit.

In singleSubmtit, they corrected this. In here, your field is taken and is sepately validated without affecting other fields or triggering their errors.

Hope you have understood this. If not, this link will help

```
www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ice/single+submit
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Using+Single+Submit

The SingleSubmit tag is a replacement by PartialSubmit, according to ICESoft information.

Cheers!

Comment: i already knew this link. In it there isn't the substantial difference between partial and single submit. i don't understand if the two things are the same thing and the only difference is that one is used in icefaces 1.x and the other in 2.x. Indeed both singlesubmit or partialsubmit  when we leave a field (either by clicking out of it or by tabbing through the fields) only that field will be submitted and processed on the server. therefore i don't understand the difference yet.

Comment: A great definition of SingleSubmit and a comparisson with PartialSubmit is placed here: [link](http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Single+Submit). Basically, the SingleSubmit attribute offers more capabilities for catching faces messages and solves many caveats of using partial submit.